# Dynamic Midi generation and playback on Android: Possible?

Tags: android, midi

Strangely I find no support for Midi in Android.
The only thing that comes close is the Jetplayer, but this only takes a existing .jet file.

I want to dynamically generate a midi file with some intervals and play it. 
I even thought about just manually creating a .jet file with a tone and then transposing it with the jet player, but it limits the transposing to -12, +12. Which is not so good for me.

There also is a ToneGenerator on Android, but it's limited to predefined tones with no way to transpose.

Does someone know how to achieve midi generation and playback on Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps [this Pragmatic Programmer thread](http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/138/topics/4103) might be of interest.

Comment: Found something there. It looks like the Mediaplayer in android does support midi files, so all I have to do now is find a existing midi generation library and use it.

Answer (score 4):

I currently settled for the dynamic generation of midi files that then are fed to the `MediaPlayer`. It's quite easy to build a simple midi file generator and the `MediaPlayer` works correctly with it.

I do have opened a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8201) for direct streaming access to the synthesizer. If you are interested in streaming midi, please rate, star, comment there.

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never, but there's a bare-bones Java MIDI library on Google Code here: http://code.google.com/p/android-midi-lib/

That can handle MIDI file generation and you can use MediaPlayer to play it back supposedly.